# Who the hell is Truth?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series

In Full Metal Alchemist, who is the character (or the concept really) of **Truth**? What does he symbolize? What is his purpose?

From what I guess, he's some sort of your inner God, because he seems to know you better than you do yourself. He knows the best way to punish you, the way that would hurt you the most. He must be tied with alchemy and alchemical knowledge, but *what* is he?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Truth himself (itself?) states,

> Who am I? One name you might have for me is the world, or you might call me the universe, or perhaps God, or perhaps the Truth. I am All, and I am One. So, of course, this also means that I am you. I am the truth of your despair, the inescapable price of your boastfulness.

Truth is a being that has no physical form, and a being that regulates all alchemical exchanges that take place. He essentially exists in order to prevent humans from "playing God" with alchemy; when human transmutation is performed, for example, Truth intervenes as it is seen as an unfair (inequivalent) exchange.

In these ways, Truth is somewhat symbolic of God. It has also been compared to gods in other mythos, such as Hera, a Greek goddess who was known to vengefully challenge heroes.

> Hera was known for her jealous and vengeful nature, most notably against Zeus's lovers and offspring, but also against mortals who crossed her, such as Pelias.
>
> — [Hera, Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hera)

However, it is important to realize that **[Truth](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Truth) is *not* [God](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Eye_of_God)**. While it is certain that they are linked in some way, God is the entity that lies within the domain of the Gate (the eye and mass of black hands that restrain his "victims").

[image: Truth, the Gate, and God] 
 (*The Gate, Truth sitting in front, and God within it. Source: [Wikia](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/File:Gate.png)*)

When an alchemist pays the toll and is forced through the Gate by Truth (and by God), they are shown all knowledge about alchemy. Their minds can only absorb so much, but enough is clear that they are able to perform their alchemy without requiring a transmutation circle.

So, what *exactly* is Truth? He is a vengeful, godlike being, who is linked to God, and governs all alchemical exchanges performed by alchemists. He has no physical form and exists only metaphysically within the mind of each alchemist.

Comment: Also, the words "Adonai" are written on the gate, which is Hebrew for "God." You can see it at 1:18 here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6Tgl4f8Rxc

Comment: Where is your proof that is he not God? This seems very speculative.  Even the wikia references you are pointing to allude that they maybe one and the same.  The point truth makes is everyone is connected, and everyone can get to the gate and  God/Truth exists within everything, they are one and the same but also personified differently. Truth maybe just an Avatar of the Ultimate Being.  This isn't necessarily contradictory as many religions observe this phenomena (Christianity with Jesus/God/Holy Spirit, or Hinduism with their "personified gods"/Single formless God/Truth).

Comment: @Quikstryke I'd call it far from speculative. There is *nothing to suggest they are the same being*. There is no proof they are not, but proving a negative is not a trivial matter. He calls himself "God" by prefacing it with "I am the called by many names," never stating that he *is* any one of them. I would agree more with your religious analogies if Truth existed as a physical being; however, he is metaphysical, just as the Gate and the Eye are. Furthermore, he is *not* an avatar of God, as he is an avatar of the person with whom he communicates.

Comment: I think you missed the point they are all the same. He states I am god, I am you, I am the universe, I am truth.  The eye refers to the eye of Providence (Personification of God): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_of_Providence, the Gate is the barrier between self and god, "Truth" is the avatar basically a personification that explains the rules of the universe, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avatar (see end of first sentence), and you is the piece of god that is but trapped outside the gate: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%80tman_%28Hinduism%29

Comment: @Quikstryke I got your point, but you seemed to ignore mine. He states, "I am the called by many names," but *never* says that he actually *is* any of those things. As far as I can tell, this is your only premise for your argument, and I see no reason at all why it should be considered "proof".

Comment: Well I think that is based on translation.  But even by what you said it can still be inferred that humans call him different names because they cant comprehend the greater, he is still implying all of those names are a single thing.  Not sure if this is allowed on here so I'll put it in a separate post incase stack deletes it (if someone can upload these images outside of this site that would be great):

Comment: Start on this page and go next few pages: http://www.mangahere.co/manga/full_metal_alchemist/v026/c108/24.html

Comment: @Quikstryke "*I am what you call.*" Just like I am what you call キルア, but that's not who I actually am. (If only.) I don't have my raw volume 26 with me, so I won't be able to actually check that until September, but I have confidence that the meaning of, "This is my what humans call me," will not change.

Comment: @killua at the end of the day you maybe right I would love to see the raw as well.  My initial point was the burden of proof is to prove he wasnt God since it seems (not just me) the internet as population seems to translate truth as god.  A simple google search "hiromu arakawa god" can confirm this as the general interpretation.  Most sites list it as such.  As this is a site for discovery I am open to and would like to see evidence against the common interpretation/translation. Does someone else have the raw? I believe however he starts by saying "kami o" addressing god and truth responds.

Comment: @Quikstryke When facing the gate, Homunculus says, "神、何を君がないのだ？" ("God, what are you not content with?") Truth says from behind, "お前は己を信じないからだ。" ("Because you don't believe in yourself.") When asked what he is, Truth says, "お前たちの世界といえば存在。ありはうちゅう。。。そして、私はお前と。" meaning "I am the being which is spoken of as the world, the existence 'universe'... and, I am called 'you'." ("God" is said in the same way as "universe", in a list.) Given the use of と (Japanese quotation) prior to いえば and at the end of his sentence, I'm convinced he's listing them as names, in the same way as he says he "is" the world.

Comment: The relationship between the entity beyond the gate and Truth is not explained. Even the wiki article you linked for Eye of God says so. Therefore, you cannot assert so definitively that "Truth is not God", nor can it be asserted that the entity beyond the gate "is God" because the wiki article states that the entity's nature is never revealed. Based on your comments above, I expect your answer would benefit from citing the manga directly.

Answer (score 10):

It is you and it is the Universe. It is everything.

When the Elric brothers train in the island, they realize the connection between the 'one' and the 'all'. They understand that everything is connected. I think that what they understand is **Truth** itself. They understand something that is in them and around them.

So basically, I don't think that **Truth** is a God (at least in the usual sense), but rather a sort of *law* that runs everything. It is in you and everywhere around you. However, it materializes itself as a humanoid form in your subconscious or whatever place that is where the gates are.

Comment: Why is it when you meet him, you are granted the ability to transmute without a circle? What changed in your understanding?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Since he's everything, I suspect... You know everything when you see him. :P But that's my speculation.

Comment: @Alenanno: If you knew *everything* by meeting him, you'd become God, not remain a human. You gain *something*, just not sure what :P

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Uhm, good point... Perhaps you know everything *human/earth-related*? So nothing supernatural? After all, alchemy is not magic.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: It's not by meeting him, but by passing through the Gate of Truth, which contains the truth / knowledge of everything. The further you travel, the more you know, but the more you pay (remember, equivalent exchange).

Comment: Perhaps it's like Zen, where going into deeper and deeper mental states you achieve a greater knowledge and understanding about the Truth behind the world and the Laws that underlie everything, but such knowledge cannot be expressed in words and must be "experienced to be believed".

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make a whole lot of sense because it is, in essence, a deus ex machina. It borrows from the concept of Dao, but by giving the thing the ability to communicate it elevates it into godhood, but then it is very useless at being a god, so all that remains is a deus ex machina there to tie up the loose ends without bothering to explain anything.

Leaving people wondering what the hell this character is supposed to be is by design. And there is no answer, since it's just a plot device to finish the story.

Answer (score 0):

### I think to understand this we have to grasp the concept of the world of Fullmetal Alchemist itself. Here's my take:

If we look inside ourselves and ask who we truly are, we'll soon realize that we can't answer that question. If our answer is "all interdependent parts of my body", we're still left with the question of who "you" in "your body" is.
We might argue it's our consciousness, but the same question still applies. The answer is, it's not found only within us. We're not cut off from the outside world we move in, we're a part of it. Just like our organs are part of us. We need air around us to breathe, we eat other living organisms to sustain ourselves and eventually sustain other organisms with ours after we die.

[That's what the Elric Brothers discover on the island.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v1PShCL4cjQ) Everything we think we are is an effect of evolution in form of a single organism inside a much greater, bigger organism. This organism, in turn, is also part of a bigger organism and so on. Our body, our society, the food chain, our planet, our galaxy... On the highest level, there is only one, which is all.

> **"All is the world, one is me. One is all and all is one."**

We perceive ourselves as individuals but are ultimately made of a single, great everything, sometimes called the world or the universe, or god, or one, or all, or truth.

---

Now, if we break down this single everything back into its first components we are left with 2 forces, orientations, flows of the world, ways of behavior, or whatever you want to call them. This was also the research of Scar's brother. There are infinite words to describe these two fundamental opposites:

1. the good, the active, the living, the positive, the evolving, the creating, the growing, the forward-moving, the known, truth, order, god, humans...
2. the bad, the passive, the dead, the negative, the regressing, the destroying, the killing, the backward moving, the unknown, deception, chaos, humans, god...

---

Good is not "good", bad is not "bad". They just are, as a part of everything and are opposites that need and birth each other.
The default state of things is that they fall apart. It's also the default state that they're being put together by the living though, that's us. There has to be both for either to occur. Because there is a set amount of energy. You cannot create something out of nothing, you have to pay an equal price.

To influence this flow of fundamental substances is what the anime calls Alchemy. There's Amestrian (inorganically oriented) and Xingese (organically oriented) Alchemy. That which allows Alchemists to perform the transmutation is the Gate of Truth. Its existence is the fantasy element about Fullmetal-Alchemist. It allows individuals to transmute matter by studying its behavior and creating a formula for it, a transmutation circle.

---

### What's inside the gate?

My guess is that inside the gate there's the incarnation of the second opposite: death, chaos, the opposite of what the living experience, the souls of the dead. The original Fullmetal Alchemist confirms this by stating that [the energy used for transmutation is taken from the tragedies of this world](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11nXBQ8CuxU) (likely referring to souls that left their bodies after death).

- Firstly this would explain why witnessing it gives you the ability to transmute without a transmutation circle that contains the matter's energy cycle. You have witnessed, integrated, and become a part of the cycle itself. As Edward says, he became something like a transmutation circle himself post-truth.

As a side note, Rose mentions, clapping your hands together is similar to praying to god. The concept of praying is to ask god (the world) for something, just like Alchemists "ask" the world to provide the energy for and execute transmutation. Praying and Alchemy follow the same concept, Alchemy/Science is just more empirical.

- Secondly, this would underline the great overarching story writing in
  Fullmetal Alchemist.

[image: Image credit]

We know that [the dwarf in the flask came from the other side of the gate](https://youtu.be/9wLJAYBY4tU?t=105). That would mean he's an incarnation of chaos within order, of literal evil. He's the ultimate antagonist. All characters get the opportunity to unite and fight one ultimate evil and grow along the way without it getting forced or with the need for a new antagonist after each chapter. It's one concluded story that conveys its ideas clearly.

[The moral of Fullmetal Alchemist is that we don't need the gate. There's no need to be supernaturally gifted or perform alchemy. There's no need to become perfect or play god's duties. We should experience life and learn what it's about instead of trying to go beyond it. Because that's the insurmountably scarce gift that was bestowed upon us. We're human. No more, no less.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iiDqtDUxahc)

---

### Why is human transmutation forbidden?

In the first place, human transmutation fails. That is because there's more to a human than their physical substance. There's their soul. Their consciousness. The experiences that shaped them. Consciousness and who a person is is something shaped during life experiences. You cannot transmute a soul or a person's experiences. The world just doesn't work that way. It only moves forward.

**Transmuting a human is the biggest taboo because it goes against the very logic of the world and the natural flow of everything.**

In the space of truth, after attempting the transmutation of his mother, Edward says his calculations for human transmutation weren't wrong, they just didn't go far enough. What he might have realized is that you'd have to pull the extinguished soul from the other side as well.

That is what the dwarf in the flask is. It is unknown how he has been extracted apart from the use of Slave #23's blood and Alchemy. We do know though that he needed a body to walk in the world. The dots of Hohenheim's master transmuting life into death in the form of blood for an extinguished soul could connect here. If this would be the case, the life -> death transmutation direction of the cycle isn't forbidden because it follows the natural flow of things.

---

### The lie of balance

At the conclusion of the story, the Homunculus gets punished by the truth. He asks the truth

> "what's wrong with seeking perfection?!"

What he didn't understand in trying to become the perfect human by cutting off his sins is that perfection doesn't exist. Perfect balance equals nothingness. ..If you try to reach the truth on your own accord, you get irony. Trying to balance for yourself unbalances another part of you. It's just not your job. Perfection is moving forward as your imperfect self and letting the world balance you.

Van Hoenheim says during the trial with his master ["if all is not included in the one then one is nothing"](https://youtu.be/xuaQNnuEDcA?t=222). Everything must always exist. The meaning of life isn't to achieve balance. Neither is it to push an extreme.
It's the process of balancing and unbalancing ourselves within the one just as much as it can handle so it gets thrown back at us with the same intensity.
Life balances itself out, always. Extremes breed opposite extremes. Balance breeds nothingness. The one that balances is the inescapable truth, the felt reality.

A real-life example would be:

> Relationships likely become boring without some unbalancing playfulness or complementary traits. They also fall apart if the partners are too different.

This concept of "not too much, not too little" works in all areas:

> How to learn. How to work. How to do sport. How we dress. How we raise our pets. How we have a conversation. How we treat our friends. How we treat our enemies. How we treat strangers. How we treat our planet. How we live.

We're all one part of the same energy and should treat others like they're us. Because they are. The dwarf in the flask, Homunculus, wanted to split himself from the unity that is everything but simultaneously become everything too. He put himself before everyone, not realizing that he is one complement with them. For this hypocrisy, he was forced to return to his origin.

---

### A note on religion

Orienting ourselves towards the good, towards life, is what we, as living beings, are made for and what brings us happiness and keeps unnecessary suffering away. Everyone already subconsciously believes that. It's what our parents and experiences taught us. If we didn't learn to orient ourselves towards life, we'd not be reading this. Because there are too many things in life to consider though, religion, in theory, provides a simplified frame of reference to stay oriented towards the good, towards living.

This also explains the conflict between certain teachings of religion and science.
As science is able to more precisely explain the world, the unknown or god, the need for a deity fades. Both religion and empirical science are ultimately an attempt to explain and simplify the same world to guide its believers towards the good, towards life. If religious (or even scientific leaders) become corrupted, they cling to and exist for power and control, driving unity towards the bad. This is illustrated with Father Cornello.

---

### So, who is Truth?

With all these presuppositions in place, we can finally say who the truth is. It is the watcher, judge, and incarnation of everything. One name you might have for it is the World, or you might call it the Universe, or perhaps God, or perhaps the Truth. It is all and it is one, so of course, this also means that it is you.